# Amazon S3 vs Github Pages - which results in faster end user page load times?

Tags: performance, github, amazon-s3, jekyll, static-site

I'm creating a static site. It's being generated by Jekyll and version controlled using git. However, purely in terms of end user speed:

**Which service offers the fastest page load times in terms of serving up a static website?**

Comment: I don't see how this is opinion-based. Response-time is measurable. Which makes it fact-based, not opinion based. Are we simply closing this because it mentions a company's name?

Comment: @LarryW. I totally agree. Thank you for chiming in on this. I really would love to know.

Answer (score 2):

Last I checked GitHub uses S3 on the backend, so should be the same.

Comment: interesting — do you know if they use a CDN?

Comment: thanks for chiming in — alas, it turns out this is incorrect. i heard from github support directly that they do not host github pages on amazon, "We aren't serving any GitHub Pages on Amazon servers. However, a few other GitHub services, such as Releases and archives, use Amazon S3 for some uploading operations."